# How to Update Two div at same time with Two different response by using ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

How to Update Two div at same time with Two different response by using ajax;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax requests are asynchronous. so you can save first response, send second request in first request callback and in second callback function update divs with first and second responses. this way you can be sure that both responses arrived and ready to be processed.